# What is the antonym of likewise?

Tags: phrase-requests, adverbs, antonyms

I want to connect the following sentences with an appropriate word.

> Violation of rights triggers war. Prevention of violation of rights prevents war.

Is the antonym of likewise suitable for this?

Comment: What are you asking here? Is it the question in the title, or the question in the text? You could just use **likewise** here instead of anything else.

Comment: *Au contraire!* Or ***on the contrary***, if you want to avoid borrowings from French. But I think you'd probably do better with something like ***correspondingly*** or ***conversely*** in your context (i.e. - the two things being juxtaposed are actually more "similar" than "different").

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think "on the contrary" is out of court: that denies the prior statement rather than extending it.

Comment: @StoneyB: I was thinking in terms of A: *I think Trump is an idiot!*, B: *Likewise*, C: ***Au contraire!** I think he's clever enough to beat both the Democrats **and** the Republicans to the White House!*

Comment: General reference. [Powerthesaurus.org/likewise/antonyms](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/likewise/antonyms)

Comment: Clearly, the opposite of _likewise_ is _hatedumb_.

Comment: Not a single word, but I'd prefer "in contrast": *Violation of rights triggers war. **In contrast**, prevention of violation of rights prevents war.*

Comment: Or *on the other hand*.

Comment: **Whereas** could be used to link both sentences into one.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - No, that's a double negative.  It needs to be either *hatewise* or *likedumb*.

Comment: Why do you want to join the sentences? Note that "A causes B, therefore prevention of A prevents B" is a logical fallacy (denying the antecedent)

Comment: I don't think you want an antonym to *'likewise'* in this context. You are saying "A implies B" and "Not A implies Not B". *'Likewise'* thus fits perfectly. If you are trying to emphasise that the second implies "B implies A" (which is a corollary of "Not A implies Not B") then *'conversely'* is fine (as suggested below), but perhaps what you are saying is that the second bit strengthens the argument, in which case perhaps *'a fortiori'*. Comment rather than an answer, as neither is an antonym of *'likewise'*.

Comment: This is just an opinion, but I think the two sentences, juxtaposed as they are, already convey the intended meaning. It is better to avoid unnecessary connectives and "transition words".

Answer (score 55):

I would consider **Conversely**.

As defined on [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/conversely):

> It is often used to introduce an idea that is different from one stated before.

Comment: This is the best option, in my opinion. In the language of mathematical logic, the first proposition is A->B while the second one is notA->notB. In logic, the technical term for this is indeed "converse" - the second proposition is the converse of the first one.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg Is not the converse of A->B B->A, and notA->notB the contrapositive of B->A? Is notAnot->B the same as notA->notB?

Comment: @RichardKayser Good point - I automatically identify a statement with its contrapositive so I was somewhat abusing the terminology. Still, I think it holds up. P.S. Hempel's paradox shows the peril of taking my approach too far...

Comment: @FelixGoldberg Any logic-based conjunction fails for the two given sentences since any logical link between the 2 is a fallacy ( A->B can neither imply nor deny notA->notB )

Comment: @msam That's why I suggest to use the term "converse". Anyone who has studied logic knows that the converse of a proposition neither denies nor implies it - the use of converse stresses this fact.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg I agree. It holds up. I'll have to look up Hempel's paradox. Thanks.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg But this is not the converse, it is the inverse. The converse of A->B is B->A as pointed out by Richard Kayser . I am not too sure "inversely" would be easily understood though.

Answer (score 33):

A useful word you rarely see is *contrariwise*:

> 'I know what you're thinking about,' said Tweedledum; 'but it isn't so, nohow.'
>
> '***Contrariwise***,' continued Tweedledee, 'if it was so, it might be; and if it were so, it would be; but as it isn't, it ain't. That's logic.'
>
> Violation of rights triggers war. Contrariwise, prevention of violation of rights prevents war.

But that "prevention of violation of" excites *horror aequi*. It would be more graceful and more emphatic to write

> Violation of rights triggers war. Contrariwise, preventing violation of rights prevents war.

Comment: 'Contrariwise' is a much rarer than 'conversely'. Also it sounds a bit too 'Alice in Wonderland'

Comment: I strongly second "conversely" as the more comfortable choice, even though on reading the OP, I also immediately said "contrariwise" in my head.  To stick closely to the antonym of likewise, "contrarily" may be the most accurate choice that doesn't sound a bit to "Alice in Wonderland."

Comment: @Xodarap777 But *contrarily* primarily suggests not the antonym of *likewise* but other senses of *contrary* -- opposed to what is usual or conventional, or FumbleFingers' "on the contrary". That's why *contrariwise* is useful. :)

Comment: I disagree.  Contrarily is most certainly "an" antonym of likewise, though it isn't as directly opposite as contrariwise.  "Do you feel likewise?" "No, I feel contrarily."  "Beautiful and slender, she was likewise deadly" vs. "Beautiful and slender, she was contrarily harmless."  "Likewise for X,..." vs "Contrarily for X,..."  The only instance wherein I wouldn't substitute contrarily as an antonym is the strange use of "likewise" as an exclamation, but I would find it strange, too, if someone used "Contrariwise!" as a single-word sentence indicating disagreement!

Comment: I need to explain the logic of the situation. If A causes B then prevention of A causes the prevention of B. I could have said it exactly in this form but i need a more acadamic way to express the logic of the idea.

Comment: @VishakyaFernando If you're speaking of your second proposition as an inference from the first, rather than a parallel to it, then you don't want anything related to *likewise*, which speaks to *similarity* between the two: you want something more like *consequently*.

Comment: *Contrariwise* is not an academic term, rather an archaic or whimsical one.

Comment: @nekomatic Not academic? It may not be used in your field, but I've employed it in LitCrit for forty years, and in Google Books I find scores of contemporary instances (and not just in transcriptions/translations of old texts or works by non-native speakers) in works on history, philosophy, neurology, economics, law, biology--and even rock and roll: "And contrariwise, musically untrained rock lovers could still appreciate the finesse and craftsmanship of classier numbers that graced the Billboard Top 100."

Comment: "Contrawise" is a contracted form of "contrariwise" that has [historical usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=contrawise&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccontrawise%3B%2Cc0), though it is even rarer than "contrariwise". I find that "contrawise" sounds more comfortable, personally.

Comment: @StoneyB I stand corrected! I've never seen it myself outside *Wonderland*, however...

Answer (score 6):

> Is the antonym of likewise suitable for this?

No. An antonym to likewise would be something like:

> conversely, otherwise, differently, however, contrarily,
>   contrariwise, on the contrary, oppositely ...

This would indicate that one statement in some way "excludes" the other statement.

What you really want to convey, is that the two statements are "similar" or "related", and that one statement follows from the other.

I think `consequently` or even simply the word `so` fits to link the two sentences:

> Violation of rights triggers war, ***consequently***, prevention of violation of rights prevents war.
>   Violation of rights triggers war, ***so***, prevention of violation of rights prevents war.

Answer (score 2):

I would use *furthermore* (which isn't an antonym of *likewise*)

> furthermore
>       in addition to what has been said

> Violation of rights triggers war. 
>   Furthermore, prevention of violation of rights prevents war.

*On the other hand* also suits well, in my opinion.

Comment: Though it should be noted that "furthermore" is not an antonym of "likewise".

Comment: But it really isn’t *further*, it’s just an implication of what has already been said.

Comment: @Jim -- causality doesn't work like that.  Cutting off your head would certainly kill you -- but refraining from cutting off your head would not bestow immortality.

Comment: @Malvolio - Not at all the same thing.  Here the implication is that  since violation triggers war, if there is no violation no war is triggered ( at least not from a violation of rights perspective)

Comment: That's what I mean: there are lots of ways a war could be triggered.  There was once a war over a soccer game.

Answer (score 2):

I would eliminate the initial period following the first 'war', insert a comma, and use the words 'while the' to connect the two sentences into one.  And then I'd likely find another way to avoid the redundancy of the term 'violation of rights' by turning into 'prevention of rights violations', or finding another way to not use the words 'prevention' and 'prevents' in the very same sentence. Perhaps substituting 'deters' for the second prevents.  Thus: Violation of rights triggers wars, while the prevention of rights violations deters war.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. But what is the answer to the question? I **think** you're saying it's *while*, although that isn't obviously an antonym of *likewise.*

Comment: Yes it is - I've often seen *while* used in this way, i.e. as a replacement for *whereas*.

Answer (score 2):

Near Antonyms: contrarily, conversely, inversely, oppositely, vice versa; diversely, unequally, variously

Antonyms: differently, dissimilarly, otherwise

Answer (score 1):

I believe "however" works as an antonym for "likewise;" however, I believe a different conjunctive adverb would fit such as "in addition" albeit "in addition" works like "likewise."

> <strike>Violation of rights triggers war; however, prevention of violation of rights prevents war.</strike>
>
> Violation of rights triggers war; in addition, prevention of violation of rights prevents war.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that likewise suits this sentence fine.

"Violation of rights triggers war. *Likewise,* prevention of violation of rights prevents war."

You could even just use a semicolon: 
"Violation of rights triggers war; preventing that violation prevents war."

But to answer the question, an antonym of likewise would be *nonetheless,* meaning "in spite of that."

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonetheless
"sometimes you can be a real jerk, but I like you nonetheless"
"it was the barest of welcomes, but it was a welcome nonetheless"